# Extractin only numbers from text with additional text ml,kg,l

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-science

I would like extract only numbers that have kg, ml, l or kilograms from my DataFrame column. I need to create a new column and extract from every row only numbers that have ml,l,kg or kilograms.

Example:

```py
data = [[1, 'detergent 5kg , 555667 ch'], [2, '009 ph, cream 10 ml'], [3, 'oliv oil 0.5 l bio, serial number 34455555'], [4, 'dddd 45, 2 kilograms eco corn flour serial number 7788696']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text'])
```

I know that I can use this to extract numbers:

```py
df['new_col'] = df.text.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

But I would like to have output in a new column with only numbers that have kilograms, ml or litre (kg, ml, l).
Something like this:

```py
5kg

10 ml

0.5 l

2 kilograms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, try:

```py
df['new_col'] = df.text.str.extract(r'(\d+[.]{0,1}\d*\s*(kg|ml|l|kilograms))')[0]
```

Outputs:

```py
   id  ...      new_col
0   1  ...          5kg
1   2  ...        10 ml
2   3  ...        0.5 l
3   4  ...  2 kilograms
```

**Edit**

As per follow up- `extract` extracts only first match - if you want all of them - try:

Input:

```py
data = [[1, '10mldetergent 5kg , 555667 ch'], [2, '009 ph, cream 10 ml'], [3, 'oliv oil 0.5 l bio, serial number 34455555'], [4, 'dddd 45, 2 kilograms eco corn flour serial number 7788696']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text'])
```

```py
df['new_col'] = df.text.str.extractall(r'(\d+[.]{0,1}\d*\s*(kg|ml|l|kilograms))')[0].groupby(level=[0]).agg(list)
```

Outputs:

```py
   id  ...        new_col
0   1  ...    [10ml, 5kg]
1   2  ...        [10 ml]
2   3  ...        [0.5 l]
3   4  ...  [2 kilograms]
```

Comment: I have a problem with some records. For example if I would have In row Id 1 text: 10mldetergent 5kg , 555667 ch. Output in my new_col would be 10 ml only, so without 5 kg. Also if I would have record with word for example 10little ... the output would be 10l. I'm interested is there a way to resolve this? I need only numbers with kilograms, millilitre, litre etc. so I do need words like 10little in my output as 10l.

Comment: I added solution for that ;)

Comment: In my example:

data = [[1, '10mldetergent 5kg , 555667 ch'], [2, '009 ph, cream 10 ml'], [3, 'oliv oil 0.5 l bio, serial number 34455555'], [4, 'dddd 45, 2 kilograms eco corn flour serial number 7788696'],[5, '75756 59498, ufg 8litttu bbb']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'text']) 

df

I'm getting 8l for the word 8littu and tis is wrong becase it's not l as litre. I don't know how to resolve this?

Comment: Hm, it depends - you can do: ```r'(\d+[.]{0,1}\d*\s*(kg|ml|l|kilograms)([^\w+]|$))'``` which will return only instances, where after unit you see any char, except another letter, but it will eliminate ```8mldetergent``` too, otherwise it will be hard to distinguish - whether it's a unit, or the beginning of another word.